# field conditions in awk; newbie

Tags: awk, operators, conditional-statements

When I write the following command:

```
awk '$3 != 0.00 && $5 < 0.2' file
```

The condition applies only if $2 is not empty.

Why? The tab is there

Comment: by default awk take tab as the field separator. This kind of condition is working for me. Can you give an example on which you are executing this condition.

Comment: The default field separator is any run of spaces, tabs, or newlines.  (Techinically, the default separator is a single space, but when the separator is a single space, fields are separated by any run of spaces, tabs, or newlines.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify to awk that you are using a tab delimiter, and that is a special case. I tested the following:

```
echo -e "a\tb\tc\td\te" | awk -F$'\t' '{print NF}'
```

The answer is 5, so it seems to work. The $ is necessary here.

Comment: Thanks! "awk -F'\t' '$3 != 0.00 && $5 < 0.2' file" did the trick.

Comment: Actually I should have mentionned that $'\t' is the syntax for expanding ANSI-C backslash-escaped characters in the text between the single quotes, in bash shell (may not work in other shells, e.g. Bourne)

Comment: I think most awks interpret the 2-character string `"\t"` as a tab character

Comment: Indeed, the Open Group spec for awk requires awk to accept `\t`.  And note that using the `$'\t'` construct is a bashism, so it is much better to omit the `$`.